# Service Fabric application failure behaviour

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I just test Service Fabric in on-premise. I tested many failure scenarios, but one of them i can't verify. How SF behave when node works well, but application has crashed? For example i have stateless web api and after single request it's fails and shutdowns (almost unpossible, but it's only assumption). SF should known about it and in next request to the same node it should redirect request for same application type hosted in any other node, until application is not starting again? Am i right? On statefull it should do the same, but rather than redirect to other node it should use replica?

I try simulate this example using ***Restart-ServiceFabricDeployedCodePackage***, but it's probably restart too fast and i can't validate my assumptions - i get timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption that Service Fabric will redirect requests to services is generally not true unless you're using the built-in Reverse Proxy (you'll know if you're using it because you will need to structure request URLs a certain way).

Assuming you are not using the built-in Reverse Proxy, then your services connect and communicate directly with each other on IP:port endpoints. Service Fabric is not in the request path. Service Fabric only provides service discovery.

SF detects process crashes. You can also report a fault from your service code. In these cases, SF will restart the process that crashed or replica that reported the fault. They may be restarted on a different node. Stateful service replicas will almost always failover to another node where an active secondary can be promoted to primary. Clients are responsible for resolving the new service endpoint or switching to a different instance if the service is stateless.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. That complicate a little bit configuration of high availability. Previous i just thinking that i configure HAProxy (load balancer) which do node health check on port 19000 and that verify for me not only that node is alive but also that is SF service running. Any other stuff like redirect to other node on app failure or upgrade i thought that will be resolved by SF. Using only load balancer with SF is very clear for clients (any logic on theirs side, any Reverse Proxy). I can deploy applications on midnight but when app fails, i must accept a little work hole.